# Qt Select At Most 1 Marker on Map

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

In my code every marker that I clicked are selected(turn into green from red). I want just 1 can change. When I click another marker the marker I clicked before turns red again. Or When I click an empty area the marker I clicked before turns red again.

In qml my Item's code:

```
Component {
    id: hazardous_img

    MapQuickItem {
        id: hazardousitem
        anchorPoint.x: image.width/4
        anchorPoint.y: image.height
        coordinate: position
        property bool isClicked: false

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onDoubleClicked: {
                mainwindow.hazardousIconClicked(mapview.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)))
            }
            onClicked: {
                if (isClicked === false) {
                    image.source = "qrc:/grn-pushpin.png"
                    isClicked = true
                } else {
                    image.source = "qrc:/red-pushpin.png"
                    isClicked = false
                }
            }
        }
        sourceItem: Image {
            id: image
            source: "qrc:/red-pushpin.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just keep a reference to the last clicked item and clear its state on the next click.

Comment: How Can I do this can you explain

Comment: @MeteKorucu I've update my answer according to folibis comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QML this is usually done with using a `ButtonGroup`, but as you're not using `AbstractButton`s you need to write it yourself. Here is my solution for it.

I've used the `ListModel` to not only store the coordinates of each marker, but also a `selected` flag which is set to `false` by default. In the delegate I'm using the selected data role to show if a marker is selected or not.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtLocation 5.15
import QtPositioning 5.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Map")

    ListModel { id: markerModel }

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
        zoomLevel: 14

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onDoubleClicked: {
                var coordinate = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y))
                var jsonObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(coordinate))
                jsonObject["selected"] = false
                markerModel.append(jsonObject)
            }

            onClicked: map.deselectAll()
        }

        MapItemView {
            model: markerModel
            delegate: markerDelegate
        }

        function deselectAll() {
            for (var i = 0; i < markerModel.count; ++i)
                markerModel.setProperty(i, "selected", false)
        }

        Component {
            id: markerDelegate

            MapQuickItem {
                id: markerItem

                required property int index
                required property real latitude
                required property real longitude
                required property bool selected

                anchorPoint.x: waypointMarker.width / 2
                anchorPoint.y: waypointMarker.height / 2
                coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(latitude, longitude)

                sourceItem: Rectangle {
                    id: waypointMarker
                    width: 20
                    height: 20
                    radius: 20
                    border.width: 1
                    border.color: mouseArea.containsMouse ? "red" : "black"
                    color: markerItem.selected ? "red" : "gray"
                }

                MouseArea {
                    id: mouseArea
                    hoverEnabled: true
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        map.deselectAll()
                        markerModel.setProperty(markerItem.index, "selected", true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: _entities should not be multiplied beyond necessity_ (Occam's razor).  In your code, if you have 1000 items you will loop all of the array to just set `selected=false` when 999 of them already has `selected=false` and only one `selected=true`

Comment: You're right, I've update my answer to avoid the multiplication. It now uses the `ListModel` directly to store the selected flag.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with yet another solution without looping over all items in the model. It just stores the index of the selected marker in a dedicated property. This has the drawback that if the model order changes the index can become invalid, also potential multi selection is hard to handle, but on the other hand it is faster because it doesn't need to iterate over all items.

I experimented a lot with [DelegateModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html), it seems to be a perfect match if one could use it in combination with `MapItemView`, because of the `groups` and the attached properties like `inGroupName`.
After that I've tried [ItemSelectionModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-itemselectionmodel.html), but it seems it is only intended to be used in combination with a view, e.g. `TreeView`. I couldn't find out how to generate a `QModelIndex` in QML without a `TreeView`.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtLocation 5.15
import QtPositioning 5.15

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Map")

    property int selectedMarker: -1

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: Plugin {
            id: mapPlugin
            name: "osm"
        }
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
        zoomLevel: 14

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onDoubleClicked: {
                var coordinate = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y))
                markerModel.append(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(coordinate)))
            }

            onClicked: root.selectedMarker = -1
        }

        MapItemView {
            model: ListModel { id: markerModel }
            delegate: markerDelegate
        }

        Component {
            id: markerDelegate

            MapQuickItem {
                id: markerItem

                required property int index
                required property real latitude
                required property real longitude

                anchorPoint.x: waypointMarker.width / 2
                anchorPoint.y: waypointMarker.height / 2
                coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(latitude, longitude)

                sourceItem: Rectangle {
                    id: waypointMarker
                    width: 20
                    height: 20
                    radius: 20
                    border.width: 1
                    border.color: mouseArea.containsMouse ? "red" : "black"
                    color: markerItem.index === root.selectedMarker ? "red" : "gray"
                }

                MouseArea {
                    id: mouseArea
                    hoverEnabled: true
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: root.selectedMarker = markerItem.index
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I promise this is the last answer on that question.

This one is using an [ItemSelectionModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-itemselectionmodel.html) and a few undocumented functions, e.g. `ListModel.index(row, col)`.

`itemSelectionModel.hasSelection` is used in the `color` binding to trigger a reevaluation in order to call `isRowSelected` and set the color accordingly whenever the selection has changed.

If the user clicks on the background the [clear()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-itemselectionmodel.html#clear-method) is called to clear the selection.

I think out of the three this is the best solution. It can be easily upgraded to allow multi selection as shown below. Also the `ItemSelectionModel` can be used by other views to show the data and selection.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtLocation 5.15
import QtPositioning 5.15
import QtQml.Models 2.15
    
ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Map")

    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: Plugin {
            id: mapPlugin
            name: "osm"
        }
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.91, 10.75) // Oslo
        zoomLevel: 14

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onDoubleClicked: function(mouse) {
                markerModel.append(map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y)))
            }

            onClicked: itemSelectionModel.clear()
        }

        MapItemView {
            model: ListModel { id: markerModel }
            delegate: markerDelegate
        }

        ItemSelectionModel {
            id: itemSelectionModel
            model: markerModel
        }

        Component {
            id: markerDelegate

            MapQuickItem {
                id: markerItem

                required property int index
                required property real latitude
                required property real longitude

                anchorPoint.x: waypointMarker.width / 2
                anchorPoint.y: waypointMarker.height / 2
                coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(latitude, longitude)

                sourceItem: Rectangle {
                    id: waypointMarker
                    width: 20
                    height: 20
                    radius: 20
                    border.width: 1
                    border.color: mouseArea.containsMouse ? "red" : "black"
                    color: {
                        itemSelectionModel.hasSelection
                        return itemSelectionModel.isRowSelected(markerItem.index) ? "red" : "gray"
                    }
                }

                MouseArea {
                    id: mouseArea
                    hoverEnabled: true
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: itemSelectionModel.select(markerModel.index(markerItem.index, 0),
                                                         ItemSelectionModel./*ClearAnd*/Select)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using ItemSelectionModel is good but manually iterating on all the delegates is not the best solution. You could instead check declaratively from the delegate if it's selected there.

something like the following in the ItemSelectionModel :
`function isItemSelected(row) { const dummyNotifier = selectedIndexes; return isSelected(model.index(row, 0));}` and in the delegate: `readonly property bool selected: itemSelectionModel.isItemSelected(model.row)`

Comment: Where do you see the manual iteration? In the onSelectioChanged() I only iterate over the relevant `ListElement`s and set the property.

Comment: Indeed it's not iterating over the delegates nut the model rows. I still believe selection state should not be stored in the model as it is more a view state than related to your data. You can share a ItemSelectionModel between multiple views if you want.

Comment: Yes that is true, I didn't manage to connect declaratively to the selection state. I'll try again.